# How do I know if a function returns string or bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte

For instance `os.listdir('.')` returns list of strings whereas `os.listdir(b'.')` returns list of bytes objects. This is only one example, but the question is for all functions returning string/bytes.

I haven't seen on official docs mentioning of the returned type. Is there some convention or generic doc for that?

Comment: Take a look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869889/what-is-the-proper-way-to-determine-if-an-object-is-a-bytes-like-object-in-pytho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869889/what-is-the-proper-way-to-determine-if-an-object-is-a-bytes-like-object-in-pytho)

Comment: It sounds like you aren't looking at the proper documentation.  `os.listdir` is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), where it clearly states:  *path* may be a path-like object. If *path* is of type `bytes` (directly or indirectly through the PathLike interface), the filenames returned will also be of type `bytes`; in all other circumstances, they will be of type `str`.

Comment: Maybe you were looking at the Python 2 documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

> path may be a path-like object. If path is of type bytes (directly or indirectly through the PathLike interface), the filenames returned will also be of type bytes; in all other circumstances, they will be of type str.

Not sure about all the other functions you are referring to

Comment: you're correct, path-like is the key term to many functions i've seen acting the same. https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to check the type of a variable you can use the builtin python function `type()`. 
For example:

```
# a function that return the parameter that you give
f = lambda x: x 
# here is how type() works
print(type(f('hey this is a string!'))) # returns <class 'str'>
print(type(f(b'hey these are bytes!'))) # returns <class 'bytes'>
print(type(f(['this','is','a','list']))) # returns <class 'list'>
print(type(f(3.1415))) # returns <class 'int'>
```

so to check if a variable contains a string or bytes...

```
def check(x):
  if type(x) is str:
    return 'this is a string!'
  elif type(x) is bytes:
    return 'i like bytes!'
  else:
    return 'ooops... unknown type :('

myStr = 'string!'
myBytes = b'bytes!'
print(check(myStr))
print(check(myBytes))
```

what you should do is simply to get the path and to check its type ;)
However the `os.listdir()` function should return bytes if the parameter you entered were bytes, else a string.
to learn more about `type()` read [this!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

hope this helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I knew the type, but the specific docs are what i've been searching for, which provides information for wider string/bytes return values.

Comment: just a straight forwarded answer. thank you very much. this is what we need.